# Changing a css attribute starting with a dash using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm trying to use the ussual method of changing a css property with javascript. The problem is that the webkit based attributes start with a dash making the javascript invalid.

```
document.getElementById('circle1').style.-webkit-animation = 'upDown 15s infinite';
```

How can I modify this code to be valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer [**to this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358892/how-to-activate-a-css3-webkit-animation-using-javascript):

```
test.style.webkitAnimationName = 'colorchange'; // you had a trailing space here which does NOT get trimmed
test.style.webkitAnimationDuration = '4s';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('circle1').style['-webkit-animation'] = 'upDown 15s infinite';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute):

```
document.getElementById('circle1').setAttribute("style", "-webkit-animation: upDown 15s infinite");
```

Comment: This will overwrite any other space-separated terms in the `style` attribute value.