# How to trigger a CSS animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am stuck trying to trigger a CSS animation.

My CSS:

```
h3[id="balance-desktop"]{
    color: black;

    -webkit-animation-name: gogreen;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-name: gogreen;
    animation-duration: 2s
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes gogreen {
    from {color: black;}
    to {color: limegreen;}
    from{color: limegreen;}
    to{color: black;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes gogreen {
    from {color: black;}
    to {color: limegreen;}
    from{color: limegreen;}
    to{color: black;}
}
```

It is a basic animation that changes color of a `h3[id=balance-desktop]` element.

The animation works when the page loads. I am trying to get it to work when I call my java script function but I am unable too.

Attempt #1:

```
function showGreenAmiamtion(){
    var test = document.getElementById("balance-desktop");
    test.style.webkitAnimationName = 'gogreen';
    test.style.webkitAnimationDuration = '4s';
}
```

Attempt #2:

```
function showGreenAmiamtion(){
    document.getElementById("balance-desktop").style.webkitAnimationName = "";
    setTimeout(function ()
    {
        document.getElementById("balance-desktop").style.webkitAnimationName = "gogreen";
    }, 0);
}
```

I tried all answers from [How to activate a CSS3 (webkit) animation using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358892/how-to-activate-a-css3-webkit-animation-using-javascript), no luck.

Is something wrong with my code?

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML so we can see what you have and help provide you with a working result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt 2 works - just cleaned up your code a bit to remove the webkit prefixes (which are a few years outdated). I'm setting the animationName to `'none'` inline, and then removing that so the element goes back to using its original CSS animation name.

Also, having multiple `from` and `to`s in a keyframe animation won't work, so I formatted it to work with percentages.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("button");
var text = document.getElementById("balance-desktop");

function turngreen() {
  text.style.animationName = 'none';
  setTimeout(function() {
    text.style.animationName = null;
  }, 0);
}

btn.addEventListener('click', turngreen);
```

```css
#balance-desktop {
  color: black;
  animation: gogreen 2s;
}

@keyframes gogreen {
  0%, 100% { color: black; }
  50% { color: limegreen; }
}
```

```html
<h3 id="balance-desktop">Heading</h3>

<button id="button">Turn Green</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

For something like this, a **[CSS Transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)** might be more simple.

Also, all major browsers support CSS3 Animations and Transitions these days, so unless you are targeting old browsers, you can drop the vendor prefixes.

```js
// Get DOM references:
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
var h3 = document.querySelector(".balance-desktop");

// Set up trigger for transition function. This is a button
// click in this example, but the function can be called anytime
// you like.
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){

  // By changing a style property on the element that had previously 
  // been set, and if that element has been set up for transitions
  // on that property, the transition will be activated.
  h3.classList.add("goGreen");
  
  // After the transition to the new style is complete
  // we'll remove that style, effectively causing a 
  // transition back to the original style. It's important
  // that the delay is set to at least the time of the transition.
  // Two seconds in this case.
  setTimeout(function(){
    h3.classList.remove("goGreen");
  },2000);
});
```

```css
.balance-desktop{
    color: black;
    /* Set the element to transition on all properties
       that have been set over the course of 2 seconds. */
    transition:2s all;
}

.goGreen {
 color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="balance-desktop">Hello</h3>
<button>Run Function</button>
```